# Drop down menu overflow issue

Tags: drop-down-menu, overflow

I am having an issue making my a drop down menu visible over the content below it. I have tried using the overflow: visible; command but it doesn't seem to work so I presume there is some sort of conflict going on. The other issue I have encountered is when you move down the menu to click on the options it closes once you get to the the point where it is not visible. I presume though that both issues are interlinked.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aXcje/

```
#menu {
height: 44px;
font-family: otto;
font-size: 42px;
word-spacing:15px;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
border:1px solid #1a1a1a;
margin-bottom: -1px;
margin-top: -1px;
background-image: url("images/menu.png");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
}
```

Website: http://www.debbie.travismoore.co.uk/

Any help is appreciated,
Cheers,
Travis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using the z-index property on the drop down menu